# C# not reading registry values from Wow6432Node on Windows Server 2012 64-bit

Tags: c#, .net, registry, windows-server-2012-r2

I am moving three Windows Services (.NET 3.5) from Windows Server 2003R2, to Windows Server 2012 R2 (.NET 4.5).

The first two went well. Reading registry settings from 
**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyCompany\MyApplication]**.

Now here´s the funny stuff - the third one only works when I store settings in 
**[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyApplication]** (whitout Wow6432Node)?

And, if I try to run the service with settings in 32-bit registry it reads the settings ok but I get this assembly binding error instead:
**System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.** The other two, using the same dll, works fine.

Any ideas? What is different in the third Windows Service?

Since all applications using the same code to read the registry I don´t think that´s the problem. Her´s the code (simplyfied) anyway.

```
    private string getRegistrySetting(string keyName)
    {
        string softwareSubkeyName = "SOFTWARE";
        using (RegistryKey softwareSubkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(softwareSubkeyName, false))
        {
            string lmSubkeyName = "MyCompany\\MyApplication;
            using (RegistryKey lmSubkey = softwareSubkey.OpenSubKey(lmSubkeyName))
            {
                return lmSubkey.GetValue(keyName).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: build the service with x86 and check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that all your executables have the target platform set to x86 (and not to AnyCPU) on the build tab of the project's  property pages (caveat: this is a per-build-configuration setting, you need to set the target platform for both Debug and Release build).

Then you need to make sure that you also deploy the 32-bit version of any third-party components such as Oracle.DataAccess. The reason is that a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit dll and vice versa.

The target platform is relevant because it determines if your process will be started as a 32-bit or 64-bit process. If your executable runs as a 64-bit process Registry and file system redirection won't be in place - as a result your process will read and write directly to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\` and not to the `Wow6432Node` subnode.

Comment: Thanks. I have cheked the build config. Project executable have target platform x86 and project librarys have 'Any CPU', in all configs. I rebuilt the whole thing again and installed it. No luck.

Comment: I also checked the Oracle.DataAccess.dll. It is the same dll as in the two other projects. 32-bit v. 4.121.2.0, runtime v4.0.30319. Specific version=False.

Comment: Does your service run as a 32-bit or as a 64-bit process? You can check this e.g. using Process Explorer (double-click on the service and check on the *Image* tab, it will tell either "Image: 64-bit" or "Image: 32-bit").

Comment: As you suspected, the application runs as a 64-bit application. The other two runs as 32-bit.

Comment: Heureka! In the project properties on the build tab, the Platform target was set to 'Any CPU' and 'Prefer 32-bit' was not checked. I checked the 'Prefer 32-bit' and it did the trick!
The other two applications was set to x86. I can´t even remember changing theese setting but obviulsly I did. 
Thank you so mutch.